# Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp site and want to add some aspx pages into that site. I published the aspx pages into a folder and put that folder to the virtual directory. As soon as I access the aspx pages, it shows the following error "Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_o5lfcfis'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page."

Comment: Copy published `bin` folder to virtual dir.

Comment: I copied the whole publish folder along with the DLL folder.

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401188/asp-net-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-app-web-z9w33txs?rq=1

Comment: Yes, already tried this approach also.

Comment: Hi , Could you delete all the temporary files in %TEMP% folder and see what happens, It might be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I deleted the files of temporary folder, but no success.

Comment: The assembly is already exist in the bin folder. But not getting the reason of error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I copied the bin directory from the aspx folder to the main dir.